# Interchange of summation and analytic continuation with absolute convergence and an analytic sum?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f_n$, $F$ be analytic on the open right half plane, and suppose that for all real $x > 0$ and all integers $k \ge 0$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n^{(k)} (x)$ converges absolutely to $F^{(k)}(x)$.

Does this imply that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n (z) = F(z)$ everywhere on the open right half plane?

Clearly without the assumption on the analyticity of $F$ this is false; I suspect it is still false, but this does knock out the usual counterexamples.

Comment: Just take for partial sums a sequence of functions that are very small in a fixed strip around the real axis but blow up otherwise. You do not need to construct anything explicitly, just apply Runge to the sequence of rectangles $[-n,n]\times[-1,1]$ united with some compact set above the line where you want a bad behaviour.

Comment: This question should be moved to the MathSE. Application of Runge's theorem gives immediate counterexamples.

Comment: With such a construction is it also obvious that the derivatives are absolutely convergent?

Comment: More precisely, that _all_ of the derivatives are absolutely convergent? If I follow @fedja's suggestion then it seems like I can no longer stop the Runge approximations at finite order when I take this into account.

Comment: Oh wait, diagonal subsequence trick.  Took me a little while but I think I got there in the end.  Thanks!

Comment: @Rafael L. Greenblatt. Do you feel like posting your A to your Q? I'm interested